# byte array to decimal convertion in java

Tags: java, udp, arrays

I am new to java. I receive the UDP data in byte array. Each elements of the byte array have the hexadecimal value. I need to convert each element to integer.

How to convert it to integer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sample code:

```
 public int[] bytearray2intarray(byte[] barray)
 {
   int[] iarray = new int[barray.length];
   int i = 0;
   for (byte b : barray)
       iarray[i++] = b & 0xff;
   // "and" with 0xff since bytes are signed in java
   return iarray;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Manually: Iterate over the elements of the array and cast them to `int` or use `Integer.valueOf()` to create integer objects.

Answer (score 1):

Function : return unsigned value of byte array.

```
public static long bytesToDec(byte[] byteArray) {
    long total = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < byteArray.length ; i++) {
        int temp = byteArray[i];
        if(temp < 0) {
            total += (128 + (byteArray[i] & 0x7f)) * Math.pow(2, (byteArray-1-i)*8); 
        } else {
            total += ((byteArray[i] & 0x7f) * Math.pow(2, (byteArray-1-i)*8));
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what OP asked. To quote: *convert* **each** *element to integer*.

Comment: if you give input as {0xf1,0x00}, then it gives output as 61696. which is decimal value of f100. I think its work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I found that may be of use to you http://blog.codebeach.com/2008/02/convert-hex-string-to-integer-and-back.html