# Convert byte array to decimal

Tags: java, arrays, decimal, hex

I have a byte array and I want to do some manipulation on the basis of the data I have in this array. The content of the byte array is in hexadecimal format.

```
byte[] signal = message.getFieldValue( "_Decoder Message" ).data();
```

This gives me the byte array with the following content

```
[ff ff 11 ff ff 82 05 00 13 00 d7 00 fc dc 03 04 00 00 01 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00 52 00 00]
```

Is it possible to convert this byte array to an array which contains values in decimal ?
Or if I am interested in any specific index how can I convert the value of that index to decimal ?

Let say I want to convert index 18 which in byte array is 01. I am using Java btw.

Thanks

Comment: "_The content of the byte array is in hexadecimal format._" can not be the case. A byte array contains bytes and nothing else.

Comment: What decimals? 32bit or 64bit IEEE?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
 public int[] bytearray2intarray(byte[] barray)
 {
   int[] iarray = new int[barray.length];
   int i = 0;
   for (byte b : barray)
       iarray[i++] = b & 0xff;
   return iarray;
 }
```

Comment: courtesy .. this so answer ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/3149118/931982 .. it seems same so I just copied from there